# Privilege violation for file or directory

Tags: parallelization, files-and-directories, scripting

hopefully somebody can help me out with the following;

I have a mathematica .wl script which uses `ParallelTable`;

When I run this locally (laptop) it works perfectly. However, when I push this to a server on a different machine, it gives the error:

> CreateDirectory::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory /u.
>
> CreateDirectory::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory /u.
>
> CreateDirectory::privv: Privilege violation for file or directory /u.
>
> General::stop: Further output of CreateDirectory::privv will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> Write::noopen: Cannot open /u/ddevetak/.Mathematica/ApplicationData/Parallel/Preferences/Preferences.m.
>
> Write::noopen: Cannot open /u/ddevetak/.Mathematica/ApplicationData/Parallel/Preferences/Preferences.m.

So the script goes through but the parallel computing is off.

Really appreciate if anybody has an idea how to fix this!

Comment: This seems as though your script is running under a user that doesn't have permission for the directory it needs to read from. The easiest, but also worst, solution might be to try using `sudo`.

Comment: Was Mathematica installed on that machine with `sudo` privileges as described here http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453 ?